# Could I specify the variable influence before building the model?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

For most genomic questions, we have ~20k genes as variables and relatively small sample size ~100 samples. We also have two variables which are extremely relevant to our Y. How should I build the model in this situation?

One suggestion I got is changing the Random Forest model to select those two important variables with higher probability. I haven't found any existing tool that I can prespecify the probability to select columns. I guess I need to change the code to get it work.

Is there any other suggestion? Build a model with those two important variables first and then integrate the gene expression data in the second layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arborist implementation is available both for R and python and is optimized for fat data sets, check out the: parameter **predProb** *probability of selecting individual predictor as trial splitter.*, [R reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rborist/Rborist.pdf). You could also perform some initial uni-variate feature filtering, before running a classic implementation of random forest.

That said, when you have 20k genes and## Heading ## only 100 observations, then some highly regularized only additive model (no interactions) is likely the only model your data can support.

Answer (score 1):

In R there are several packages with that you can choose variables with higher probability. For example in the ranger package you can specify the split.select.weights argument. Or in randomForestSRC you can specify the xvar.wt argument.